# Sending JSON events to Azure Event Hub using Python program

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

Newbie to Azure Stream analytics. I am sending events to Azure Event Hub with below Python program by serializing the respone\data to `JSON` format so that it can be read by the Stream Analytics job input. However, there is something either wrong or I am missing because of which I can not view the test data in the Stream Analytics job.

```
import asyncio
import time
import requests
import json
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.eventhub import EventData

connection_str = 'XXX'
consumer_group = 'XXX'
eventhub_name = 'XXX'

async def run():
    # create a producer client to send messages to the event hub
    # specify connection string to your event hubs namespace and
    # the event hub name
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(connection_str, consumer_group=consumer_group, eventhub_name=eventhub_name)

    async with producer:
        # create a batch        
        event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch(partition_id='1')

        while True:
            # add events to the batch
            response = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")

            data = json.loads(response.text)        

            event_data_batch.add(EventData(data))

            time.sleep(5)

            # send the batch of events to the event hub
            await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

Comment: First validate that your sends are successful. Do you see valid JSON payload if you read events from the hub directly via some simple client such as Service Bus Explorer?